# Yii - GET param in URL path

Tags: php, yii

I have the following URL rule in **config/main**:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    //'appendParams' => true, // I've tried it without success.
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'rules' => array(
        // other rules...
        'experience/search/<param:\w+>' => 'experience/searchExperiences',
```

I use a form with the `GET` method and I expect it to produce a URL like this:

http://site.dev/experience/search/Viseu

But what I get is:

http://site.dev/experience/search?searchText=Viseu

--

This is the form part:

```
<form action="/experience/search" method="get" class="search-form">
    <div class="cell">
<?php
        $this->widget(
            'zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete',
            array(
                'id' => "search-text",
                'name' => "searchText",
                'options' => array(
                    'minLength' => '3',
                ),
                'source' =>
                    'js: function(request, response) {
                        getSuggestions(request, response);
                    }',
            )
        );
?>
    </div>
```

--

How could Yii be set up to do that?

Comment: Be aware that this is impossible to do without any JavaScript in the browser since a form (without JavaScript) cannot be submitted to a URL constructed from form data (except for the query string with GET method).

Comment: @Lukas Can you suggest an example? How should I prepare my form to do that with JavaScript? Maybe `CActiveForm` has something. Let me see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule used: `'experience/search/<param:\w+>' => 'experience/searchExperiences',`

JavaScript code added on **submit**:

```
$('#form-search').submit(function(event) {
    var searchText = $('#search-text').val();
    $('#form-search').attr("action", '/experience/search/' + searchText);
});
```

Changed the form's **method** to `POST`:

```
<form id="form-search" action="/experience/search" method="post" class="search-form">
```

---

I will still wait for any better suggestion.

Comment: @Lukas Is this solution resembling your first comment?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the name of the GET variable in your URL rule:

```
'experience/search/<searchText:(.*)>' => 'experience/searchExperiences',
```

I also changed `\w+` to `(.*)` as the first one only matches alphanumeric characters. The latter one matches all characters.

Comment: Please show us the code where you are calling the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can only get the URL right if you use:

```
Yii::app()->createUrl(
    'experience/search',
    array(
        'param' => 'whatever'
    )
);
```